Why Does Blazor Require Refresh for Interactive Mode to Work?
I have the following code on my Blazor App. I'm using the Server and Client template.
@page "/todo"
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<h1>Todo</h1>
<br/>

<ul>
    @foreach (Task task in tasks)
    {
        <li>
            <input value="task.IsDone" @bind="task.IsDone" type="checkbox" />
            @task.Name
            <button @onclick="() => DeleteTask(task)">️</button>
        </li>
    }
    <br/>
    <input value=@name type="text" @oninput="e => name = e.Value.ToString()" />
    <button @onclick="AddTask">Submit</button>
</ul>

@code {
    string? name;

    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task> {};

    private void AddTask()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            tasks.Add(
                new Task { IsDone =  false, Name = name}
            );
            name = string.Empty; // Clear the input after adding the task
        }

        Console.Write(tasks);
    }

    private void DeleteTask(Task task)
    {
        tasks.Remove(task);
        Console.Write("Hello World");
    }

    public class Task {
        public bool IsDone { get; set; }
        public required  string  Name { get; set; }
    }
}

When I ran this on my browser I need to refresh the todo page to make it work and make it interactive.
I'm running on version .NET-9 on my Mac.
I've tried switching to InteractiveAuto but I'm getting the same issue as well. Tried this on version .NET-8 but still the same issue.

There's nothing wrong with the code you've shown.  Deploy a Blazor Server  => Per Page/Component and paste in your code.  My demo project is here - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/SO79296159.  It works.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis it's not that there's something wrong with the code. It's more like there's something wrong with blazor itself. For the code above to work I need to refresh the page before it becomes interactive.

There's nothing wrong with Blazor, but there will be something wrong with your solution/project setup.  Produce a [MRE] that demonstrates your problem and publish it to Github.
